# synthesizing long parameter strings

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

When consuming a JSON string, the parameters can be deeply nested, making reading/checking tedious:

```
update(capture_created: params[:data][:object][:created], capture_currency: params[:data][:object][:currency]  
...[...] and so on...
```

In what way can a node `params[:data][:object]` be represented only once and be thus able to handle the child values as a parameter?

Comment: `object_param = params[:data][:object]`, use thusly `object_param[:created]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can.

You could grab the inner hash in a local variable as dbugger mentioned:

```
p = params[:data][:object]
update(capture_created: p[:created], capture_currency: p[:currency], ...)
```

Or you could use [`#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-tap) or [`#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-then) (depending on what return value you want from the expression):

```
# This evaluates to params[:data][:object]
params[:data][:object].tap do |p|
  update(capture_created: p[:created], capture_currency: p[:currency], ...)
end

# This evaluates to whatever update returns
params[:data][:object].then do |p|
  update(capture_created: p[:created], capture_currency: p[:currency], ...)
end
```

If the keys in the nested hash only need to be consistently renamed (i.e. add a "capture_" prefix) then [`#transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys):

```
update(params[:data][:object].transform_keys { |k| "capture_#{k}" })
```

is an option. String keys are fine with an ActiveRecord `#update` call but you could get symbols if you really want them:

```
update(params[:data][:object].transform_keys { |k| :"capture_#{k}" })
```

You might want to include a [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-slice) call if you want to ensure that you're only accessing certain keys:

```
update(params[:data][:object].slice(:created, :currency, ...).transform_keys { |k| :"capture_#{k}" })
```